# Using iZ3 for bit vector operations

Tags: z3

I was trying to use iz3 for extracting interpolants. It seems to work fine for examples given in the documentation page. I tried to run iz3 for a example which Z3 conformed as UNSAT. But when i used iZ3 the following error popped up

iZ3: unsupported Z3 operator in expression
 (bvule bv100[101] main.a'64'0)
iZ3: unsupported Z3 operator in expression
 (bvadd main.a'64'0 main.b'64'0)
Segmentation fault

Does iZ3 support only theories of AUFLIA and not QF_AUFBV ?
Is there a way I can get interpolants for QF_AUFBV which supports bit_vector operation as above?
I used iZ3 which was in z3 4.1 version

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe interpol (http://ultimate.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/smtinterpol/docu.html) and mathsat (http://mathsat.fbk.eu/) could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, iZ3 supports only AUFLIA.